# numpy array distance matrix ascending order, same to indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have both numpy array which is distances and indices

[Image 1 - indices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcqgh.png)

[Image 2 - distances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO22H.png)

Let say I want to sort the distances into ascending order which is smallest to biggest values, but I also want to ensure the indices array follow back the order after the distances sorted.

[the result of distances array after sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1mOv.png)

[the result of indices follow back the order of distances array after sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V6UW.png)

My question here is I know how to sort the distances array by ascending order, but I don't know how to make the indices also follow the order after the distances sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [`np.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) is what you're after. It returns the indices that would sort a given array. You can use it to determine the indices that would sort your distances, then use this array to sort both the distances and the indices:

```py
import numpy as np

distances = np.random.rand(20)
indices = np.random.rand(20)

sorter = np.argsort(distances)
distancse = distances[sorter]
indices = indices[sorter]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Anyway, I have used another approach which is put distances and indices as one dataframe and convert back to array! But your approach much shorter!